# Drawing a correlation graph in matplotlib

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib, data-visualization

Suppose I have a data set of discrete vectors with `n=2`:

```
DATA = [
    ('a', 4),
    ('b', 5),
    ('c', 5),
    ('d', 4),
    ('e', 2),
    ('f', 5),
]
```

How can I plot that data set with matplotlib so as to visualize any correlation between the two variables?

Any simple code examples would be great.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Joe Kington has the correct answer, but your `DATA` probably is more complicated that is represented. It might have multiple values at 'a'. The way Joe builds the x axis values is quick but would only work for a list of unique values. There may be a faster way to do this, but this how I accomplished it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def assignIDs(list):
    '''Take a list of strings, and for each unique value assign a number.
    Returns a map for "unique-val"->id.
    '''
    sortedList = sorted(list)

    #taken from
    #http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-python-whilst-preserving-order/480227#480227
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    uniqueList =  [ x for x in sortedList if x not in seen and not seen_add(x)]

    return  dict(zip(uniqueList,range(len(uniqueList))))

def plotData(inData,color):
    x,y = zip(*inData)

    xMap = assignIDs(x)
    xAsInts = [xMap[i] for i in x]


    plt.scatter(xAsInts,y,color=color)
    plt.xticks(xMap.values(),xMap.keys())


DATA = [
    ('a', 4),
    ('b', 5),
    ('c', 5),
    ('d', 4),
    ('e', 2),
    ('f', 5),
]


DATA2 = [
    ('a', 3),
    ('b', 4),
    ('c', 4),
    ('d', 3),
    ('e', 1),
    ('f', 4),
    ('a', 5),
    ('b', 7),
    ('c', 7),
    ('d', 6),
    ('e', 4),
    ('f', 7),
]

plotData(DATA,'blue')
plotData(DATA2,'red')

plt.gcf().savefig("correlation.png")
```

My `DATA2` set has two values for every x axis value. It's plotted in red below:
[image]

**EDIT**

The question you asked is very broad. I searched 'correlation', and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence) had a good discussion on Pearson's product-moment coefficient, which characterizes the slope of a linear fit. Keep in mind that this value is only a guide, and in no way predicts whether or not a linear fit is a reasonable assumption, see the notes in the above page on [correlation and linearity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence). Here is an updated `plotData` method, which uses `numpy.linalg.lstsq` to do linear regression and `numpy.corrcoef` to calculate Pearson's R:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def plotData(inData,color):
    x,y = zip(*inData)

    xMap = assignIDs(x)
    xAsInts = np.array([xMap[i] for i in x])

    pearR = np.corrcoef(xAsInts,y)[1,0]
    # least squares from:
    # http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html
    A = np.vstack([xAsInts,np.ones(len(xAsInts))]).T
    m,c = np.linalg.lstsq(A,np.array(y))[0]

    plt.scatter(xAsInts,y,label='Data '+color,color=color)
    plt.plot(xAsInts,xAsInts*m+c,color=color,
             label="Fit %6s, r = %6.2e"%(color,pearR))
    plt.xticks(xMap.values(),xMap.keys())
    plt.legend(loc=3)
```

The new figure is:
[image]

Also flattening each direction and looking at the individual distributions might be useful, and their are examples of [doing this in matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/scatter_hist.html):
[image]

If a linear approximation is useful, which you can determine qualitatively by just looking at the fit, you might want to subtract out this trend before flatting the y direction. This would help show that you have a Gaussian random distribution about a linear trend.

Comment: Hi Yann.. Thanks for the script. I didn't understand about unique list part. You are just converting floating point values to integers. The x-axis still contains duplicate values right?

Answer (score 7):

I'm a bit confused... There are several ways to do something along those lines.  The first two that come to mind are a simple stem plot or a scatter plot.

Are you just wanting to plot things using a stem plot like this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = [
    ('a', 4),
    ('b', 5),
    ('c', 5),
    ('d', 4),
    ('e', 2),
    ('f', 5),
]
labels, y = zip(*data)

x = range(len(y))
plt.stem(x, y)
plt.xticks(x, labels)
plt.axis([-1, 6, 0, 6])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Or a scatter plot like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = [
    ('a', 4),
    ('b', 5),
    ('c', 5),
    ('d', 4),
    ('e', 2),
    ('f', 5),
]
labels, y = zip(*data)

x = range(len(y))
plt.plot(x, y, 'o')
plt.xticks(x, labels)
plt.axis([-1, 6, 0, 6])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Or something else entirely?